# Kitematic Docker: "-D start default returned non zero exit code..."

Tags: docker

This is what I keep getting in the screenshot. Clicking both buttons bring up spinner which never goes away.

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This destroyed me for a very long time and was super frustrating!

I found a forum that had the advice, but can't find it now.

Go to:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxdrv
```

Right click **VBoxDrv.inf**  and choose **Install**

Open administrative command prompt

```
sc start vboxdrv
docker-machine rm default
docker-machine -D create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 default
```

I also opened VirtualBox   File>Preferences>Networks  and removed all the interfaces.

Then rebooted and ran  Docker Quickstart Terminal   (from start menu search)

good luck